# What are/How to edit cache files for opencart website

Tags: caching, system, opencart, country, zones

Hi all am a noob on the rise with web development and design and I am trying to edit a file that I found that seems to be controlling some information about world countries. More specifically I want to add a zone to a country. This file is part of the opencart e-commerce suite. It is located here: system/cache and is called cache.zone.16 and I openned it with notepad. the contents are as follows:

```
 a:31:{i:0;a:5:
{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"284";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:7:"Acklins";s:4:"code";s:3:"ACK";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"285";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:13:"Berry Islands";s:4:"code";s:3:"BER";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:2;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"286";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:6:"Bimini";s:4:"code";s:3:"BIM";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:3;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"287";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:11:"Black Point";s:4:"code";s:3:"BLK";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:4;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"288";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:10:"Cat Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"CAT";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:5;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"289";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:13:"Central Abaco";s:4:"code";s:3:"CAB";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:6;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"290";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:14:"Central Andros";s:4:"code";s:3:"CAN";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:7;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"291";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:17:"Central Eleuthera";s:4:"code";s:3:"CEL";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:8;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"292";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:16:"City of Freeport";s:4:"code";s:3:"FRE";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:9;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"293";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:14:"Crooked Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"CRO";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:10;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"294";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:17:"East Grand Bahama";s:4:"code";s:3:"EGB";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:11;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"295";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:5:"Exuma";s:4:"code";s:3:"EXU";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:12;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"296";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:9:"Grand Cay";s:4:"code";s:3:"GRD";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:13;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"297";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:14:"Harbour Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"HAR";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:14;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"2908";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:9:"Hope Town";s:4:"code";s:3:"HOP";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:15;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"299";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:6:"Inagua";s:4:"code";s:3:"INA";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:16;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"300";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:11:"Long Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"LNG";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:17;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"301";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:12:"Mangrove Cay";s:4:"code";s:3:"MAN";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:18;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"302";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:9:"Mayaguana";s:4:"code";s:3:"MAY";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:19;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"303";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:14:"Moore's Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"MOO";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:20;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"304";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:11:"North Abaco";s:4:"code";s:3:"NAB";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:21;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"305";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:12:"North Andros";s:4:"code";s:3:"NAN";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:22;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"306";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:15:"North Eleuthera";s:4:"code";s:3:"NEL";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:23;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"307";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:13:"Ragged Island";s:4:"code";s:3:"RAG";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:24;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"308";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:7:"Rum Cay";s:4:"code";s:3:"RUM";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:25;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"309";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:12:"San Salvador";s:4:"code";s:3:"SAL";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:26;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"310";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:11:"South Abaco";s:4:"code";s:3:"SAB";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:27;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"311";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:12:"South Andros";s:4:"code";s:3:"SAN";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:28;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"312";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:15:"South Eleuthera";s:4:"code";s:3:"SEL";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:29;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"313";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:13:"Spanish Wells";s:4:"code";s:3:"SWE";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}i:30;a:5:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"314";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"16";s:4:"name";s:17:"West Grand Bahama";s:4:"code";s:3:"WGB";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}}
```

The problem is this, I am trying to open an online store using opencart because its free and am broke but I've notice that when I was trying to register a fake account to test it out with my new design I noticed something strange. The capital of the Bahamas, which is Nassau, is missing from this list. And thats kind of huge issue because Nassau is where the majority of the population of the Bahamas lives. So can someone be so kind as to offer some advice for this problem? Where to look, something to read, perhaps even a solution.

Thank You;
Eulond Kelly III

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login to admin panel and go to `System > Zones`.
2. Then click on 'Insert' button and enter the needed information.
3. Click on save button.

That's all !!

Comment: Sorry bro didnt know how to do that